# In how many ways can you place 6 differently coloured balls in 4 differently coloured boxes?

Tags: combinatorics

If all boxes were identical I would just use Stirling numbers to find the answer, but since both the balls and the boxes are different I'm lost.

How do I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every ball you have four distinct options. Use the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

The answer is $4^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Each ball can independently go in any of the $4$ boxes, so multiplying all those possibilities yields $4^6=4096$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the differences in color make things easier, not more difficult. For each ball, we independently choose a box in which to put that ball. That gives us $4^6$ possibilities in total.